# What cipher suites do Mail Clients (Thunderbird, Outlook, ...) support?

Tags: tls, email, cipher-selection

This question is related to [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/1156713/do-common-mail-clients-support-301-redirects-for-loading-images).

What cipher suites do Mail Clients (Thunderbird, Outlook, ...) support?

I know and appreciate the service of SSLLabs where I can see the browsers' capabilities in regard to cipher suites. But also mail clients negotiate TLS connections when loading content via https (e.g. images in newsletters).
But I was not able to plug the correct search terms into Google to see which mail client supports which protocol version and which cipher suites.

Answer (score 2):

Thunderbird uses the NSS library like Firefox, so look at the Firefox report for the ciphers. Similar Outlook uses SChannel like IE/Edge so look at these reports. Apart from that you can simply find out what a specific implementation uses by running a packet capture and then look at the cipher suites offered by the client in the first record of the TLS handshake (i.e. ClientHello).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374757(v=vs.85).aspx) cipher suite support only depends on the Windows version. So is there no difference between the different Outlook versions when they run on the same Windows?

Comment: @HorstKevin: unless Microsoft specifically configured Outlook to not use the default cipher set different version of Outlook on the same OS should show the same ciphers.